# How to change starting ID number

Tags: sharepoint

Can I change the initial ID number of a List?

I can create a tool that inserts a hundred of items and deletes then to change ID Value. But it doesn't sound good for me. There is another way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately . there is no other way to change ID.

but may be you can add a new Calculated Column "Custom-ID" with formula something like

=1000+ID

that way it will always have value start 1001 onward.

tx , Sandeep

Also

Comment: It isn't what I was looking for, but it is a solution. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can't use ID in a calculated column. The answer is not right

Comment: @mohsenof you cannot use ID, certainly

Answer (score 0):

You may also do as Sandeep said, but instead the Calculated value formula would be subtracting from whatever your starting ID value is.  For instance, mine started with the value of 37 and want it to start at 1 so the Calculated value would be =ID-36

Answer (score 0):

No , You Can Do That Easily :

```
ALTER TABLE table AUTO_INCREMENT = 1001
```

Comment: *No* is an answer to *Is there another way*? It looks a bit confusing at first sight

Comment: it's not confusing , easy just alter the table and it will change , (It's Works) , I Try it and working perfectly

Comment: You didn't understand - it's confusing to which question you answer *No*